# passing dynamic value from AJAX to custom parameter in jQuery dataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I'm using dataTable with server side processing. I want to send token as custom parameter to the server. Token is set by AJAX. When AJAX request on dataTable fired, token parameter that send always null. I think it is because AJAX request on dataTable fired before get token process finished. Here are ways that I already tried.

**1. Using ajax.data**

```
    function GetToken() {
        var token;
        $.get("/User/GetToken?_=" + new Date().getTime(), function (token) {
            token= token;
        });
        return token;
    }

    var dataTable = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
        serverSide: true,
        pagingType: 'full_numbers',
        scrollY: false,
        scrollX: true,
        sort: false,
        fixedColumns: true,
        autoWidth: true,
        language: {
            paginate: {
                first: "&lt;&lt;",
                previous: "&lt;",
                next: "&gt;",
                last: "&gt;&gt;",
            }
        },
        pageLength: 10,
        lengthMenu: [[2, 5, 10, 25, 50], [2, 5, 10, 25, 50]],
        columns: [
                { "data": "Name", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Address", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Gender", "autoWidth": true },
        ],
        ajax: {
            url: '@Url.Action("LoadData", "Student")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { token: GetToken() }
            dataSrc: "Data"
        }
    });
```

**2. Using preXhr.dt**

```
    var dataTable = $('#dataTable')
        .on('preXhr.dt', function (e, settings, data) {
            $.get("/User/GetToken?_=" + new Date().getTime(), function (token) {
                data.token = token;
            });
        })
        .DataTable({
            serverSide: true,
            pagingType: 'full_numbers',
            scrollY: false,
            scrollX: true,
            sort: false,
            fixedColumns: true,
            autoWidth: true,
            language: {
                paginate: {
                    first: "&lt;&lt;",
                    previous: "&lt;",
                    next: "&gt;",
                    last: "&gt;&gt;",
                }
            },
            pageLength: 10,
            lengthMenu: [[2, 5, 10, 25, 50], [2, 5, 10, 25, 50]],
            columns: [
                    { "data": "Name", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Address", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Gender", "autoWidth": true },
            ],
            ajax: {
                url: '@Url.Action("LoadData", "Student")',
                type: 'POST',
                dataSrc: "Data"
            }
        });
```

**3. Add looping for delay on preXhr.dt**

```
    var isTokenChange = false;
    var dataTable = $('#dataTable')
        .on('preXhr.dt', function (e, settings, data) {
            $.get("/User/GetToken?_=" + new Date().getTime(), function (token) {
                data.token= token;
                isTokenChange = true;
            });

            while(!isTokenChange) {

            }

            isTokenChange = false;
        })
        .DataTable({
            serverSide: true,
            pagingType: 'full_numbers',
            scrollY: false,
            scrollX: true,
            sort: false,
            fixedColumns: true,
            autoWidth: true,
            language: {
                paginate: {
                    first: "&lt;&lt;",
                    previous: "&lt;",
                    next: "&gt;",
                    last: "&gt;&gt;",
                }
            },
            pageLength: 10,
            lengthMenu: [[2, 5, 10, 25, 50], [2, 5, 10, 25, 50]],
            columns: [
                    { "data": "Name", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Address", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Gender", "autoWidth": true },
            ],
            ajax: {
                url: '@Url.Action("LoadData", "Student")',
                type: 'POST',
                dataSrc: "Data"
            }
        });
```

For third way, it's works but I think it's not a good solution. My question is what is a good solution to hold or delay ajax request on datatable until token has received?

Answer (score 1):

You can chain your calls, Only when you receive a token fire the datatable initialization.

```
function GetToken() {
    var token;
    $.get("/User/GetToken?_=" + new Date().getTime(), function (token) {
        initializeTable(token);
    });
}

initializeTable(token){
// Here initialize ur data table with the passed token.
}
```

Comment: This is a correct answer.  More elegantly this could be done in a `(function() {...})` struct i.e self exeucting function that fires the datatable initialisation as soon the server responds back.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao thanks for your answer. But I think your implementation only get token once and will use same token for all events in datatable (go to other pages, searching, etc). Actually, I want to use different token every time I get data using ajax request on datatable because there is token validation on server side which is check whether token is expired or not. So I need to get new token first before doing ajax request to get data. Do you have idea about it?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
dataTable.context[0].ajax.data.yourCustomValue = value;
```

Since my variable name is bwsValue:

```
var dataTable = $('#users-grid').DataTable( {
    "dom": 'lrtip',
    "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax":{
        url :"users_list.php?active="+active,
        "data": {
            "bwsValue": 1
        },
        type: "post",
    }
});
```

I can now set the data to:

```
dataTable.context[0].ajax.data.bwsValue = 2;
```

Answer (score -1):

You do not want to do a async request in this case, so instead of using $.get try something like this (async:false):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async:false,
    url: "/User/GetToken?_=" + new Date().getTime(),
    success: function(token, textStatus, xhr) {
        data.token = token;
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not async? He can always chain the calls.

Comment: sure he can, but if he doesn't want to rewrite the whole ting async:false will work.

Comment: Yes it will work, but is async not a better design as it will not block the user thread.

Comment: This is an absolutely horrible "solution". It solves a beginners lack of understanding of the asynchronous execution flow (**no offense**, we have all been there!) by making the code even more hackish.

Comment: Hehe....wow..quite a feedback. Relax..I do know async execution very well. I have apparently misunderstood the problem. But now I've learned my lesson..